# Display images in observable collection one after the other as user scrolls in windows phone 8

Tags: json, windows-phone-8

I have a json array of image URLs added into an observable collection and I want to display the first image on the page such that when a user scrolls horizontally, next or previous images in the array shall display on the screen. Help me achieve this.

Here's how I download the image URLs via json and add them to the observable collection

```
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private ObservableCollection<readPageModel> readPages = new ObservableCollection<readPageModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<readPageModel> Read_Pages
    {
        get
        {
            return readPages;
        }
        set
        {
            readPages = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Read_Pages"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void DownloadData()
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += client_DownloadStringCompleted;
        client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://########/mob/ranges/id/3/limit/10/offset/0/r_id/6", UriKind.Absolute));
    }


    private void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
            {
                string data = e.Result;
                var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<readModel[]>(data);
                foreach (var x in items)
                {
                    Read_Pages.Add(x);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take scrollviwer in the xaml after this within this scrollviewer take stack panel with horizontal orientation. and then from c# code add image control to this stack panel.

Comment: Praveen, I initially had it just as you've said but would like to scroll through the images just as the photo viewer default app in windows phone.

Answer (score 0):

You can have one image control in content panel and implement below code :

```
public Page()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    GestureListener gestureListener = GestureService.GetGestureListener(ContentPanel);
    gestureListener.DragCompleted += gestureListener_DragCompleted;
//set the initial image to Image control
}

void gestureListener_DragCompleted(object sender, DragCompletedGestureEventArgs e)
{
    // User flicked towards left
    if (e.HorizontalVelocity < 0)
    {
        // Load the next image if Downloaded
    }
    // User flicked towards right
    if (e.HorizontalVelocity > 0)
    {
        // Load the previous image
    }
}
```

you would also needed to have one variable for tracking the index of image to be loaded

Comment: So I shouldn't add the images in a listbox?